# Is it possible to create a designer for visual studio like the WinForms designer for a different kind of classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create a system, which processes tasks according to a dataflow network. The network is supposed to be created as something like a plug-in by the users of my system. It is created as a C# assembly containing the network as a type (class) and I would like to provide a visual editor to the user for creating and editing the network. (Editing would consist of adding/removing tasks, moving them around, creating connections between them, ...)

Ideally this would work like the WinForms designer providing visual and interactive editing capabilities integrated into Visual Studio (if possible with the ability to also view the auto-generated source code simultaneously).

Is there a way to create such an editor and register it in VS to be used for types derived from my base type? Any hint regarding feasability, which interface needs to be implemented (?), where stuff needs to be registered and how it needs to be distributed to my user would be greatly appreciated.

For Clarification: I am not looking for a tool to create a data model (visually). To be precise, it is more like this:

```cs
// for declaring the content of a task group
public class TaskAttribute: Attribute
{
    public TaskAttribute(Type type, string name) {...}
}

// for declaring the flow of data
public class ConnectionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ConnectionAttribute(string source, string output, string destination, string input) {...}
}

// basic task class
public abstract class Task
{
    ...
}

// basic task group class
public abstract class TaskGroup : Task
{
    ...
}

// one actual task with a payload of executable code
public class Foo : Task
{
    ...
}

// a second task with payload code
public class Bar : Task
{
    ...
}

/* this construct is, what I want to visually create and edit
through some extension of visual studio:
the group of subtasks (or more like a tree) 
and all data flowing between these tasks
*/
[Task(typeof(Foo), "foo")]
[Task(typeof(Bar), "bar")]
[Connection("foo", "output2", "bar", "input1")]
public class FooBar : TaskGroup
{
}
```

Now I am looking for a way, to create a visual editor, which would allow me to create and edit things like this $FooBar$ class, and tell visual studio to use said editor/designer, so my users do not need to write or read and interpret the textual description in the source code, but can use some visualization and mouse interaction instead.

The solution to use a data modelling SDK as mentioned in the comments seems excessive for this purpose and judging from a first glanse at the referenced introduction, I am not really sure, how much freedom there is in creating the actual editor for the my users data. Is there a way to just hook up a dedicated editor without the formal overhead?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources (such as libraries) is off-topic for Stack Overflow, but the term you're looking for is a "diagram designer". Edit: oh, you want a Visual Studio extension or something, like the "old" Entity Framework's EDMX designer? That's not as trivial, look at @Damien's comment.

Comment: [Modelling SDK for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/modeling-sdk-for-visual-studio-domain-specific-languages?view=vs-2019). It's got... quite a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

See [Create custom editors and designers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-editors-and-designers?view=vs-2019) and [Document data and document view in custom editors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/document-data-and-document-view-in-custom-editors?view=vs-2019) in VS extensibility documentation.